# Installing Firefox 56

Tags: software-installation, firefox, mozilla

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (it works best on my older system). I had upgraded to Firefox 57 and, after days of trying to make it work, I removed it from my system (I still have the `~/.mozilla` directory). I want to reinstall v. 56 (I know about the ESR version but do not want it as it updates along the lines of 57).

I would like to know how to install FF v56. I have downloaded firefox-56.0.2.tar.bz2 and tried installing using the instructions [located here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) but I end up with a separate directory from my mozilla directory. I am just looking for a simple, clean method for manually installing FF 56. Any ideas?

```
ls /var/cache/apt/archives/ | grep firefox
firefox_57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.4_i386.deb
firefox-locale-en_57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.4_i386.deb
```

**NOTE: The reason the other question/answer is not related as I am not downgrading, rather I am re-installing.**

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `ls /var/cache/apt/archives/ | grep firefox` . This will tell us if the FF56 package is still in your local package cache. The FF56 packages is no longer available from the Ubuntu repositories, but is available from Launchpad.

Comment: I'd go here, under `Builds` pick your arch. On the result page scroll down to the .deb packages, download the firefox.deb & whichever locale .deb matches your language. After dl, place both in an empty folder, cd to that folder in a terminal & `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/56.0+build6-0ubuntu0.14.04.2  If you liked the Ubuntu start page go here, download & also install with dpkg.  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubufox/3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 Then don't allow updates to firefox or pin as mentioned elsewhere

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I'll wait until v57 is a bit more mature before upgrading again. My updates are done through the software updater, which is not automatic so I should be good there as for updates.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question closed. Most of the answers to the linked question apply just as much to new Firefox installations.